# Pass gallery image in ImageView to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, imageview, android-gallery

I am making a memegenerator.
I have a function that opens the gallery and the user can choose an image.This image is then set to the ImageView.
I want to send this image to another activity wherein I can edit the image.
How can I do this?

A sincere request to anyone who is answering this question-I am a beginner and i would like detailed answers or explanations.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please pass your image uri to your next activity instead of passing the whole bitmap. Passing bitmap is not recommended.

Comment: how can i do that?
how can i know the uri or path of the image view?

Comment: You can see the following blog(http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/) for getting the uri. You get it in your onActivityResult callback method of activity.  PS: It's not my blog post and thanks the person for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the image locally and add the path as an Intentextra when starting the other activity, like this:

```
String pathToImage = xxx;
Intent i = new Intent(Photoactivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("imagePath", pathToImage);
```

And in the destination Activity:

```
String imagePath = i.getStringExtra("imagePath");
//After this load the image from disk
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Following Steps to get Image in the Next Activity:

**1. Set ImageView Property Like this:**

```
imageView.setDrawingCasheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b=imageView.getDrawingCashe();
```

**2. Start a new Activity via Intent like this:**

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Bitmap",b);
startActivity(i);
```

**3. In the Next Activity Write this:**

```
Intent i=getIntent();
Bitmap b=i.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: this method crashes my app when i press the button that moves it to the next activity